# Importing requirements from .csv file in Enterprise Architecture with specifying Relationship among requirements

Tags: csv, enterprise-architect

how to import requirements from .csv file in Enterprise Architecture with specifying  relationship among requirements such as generalization or aggregation

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it's not possible: CSV import only allows import of elements, not relationships.

You can nest elements inside one another using the Preserve Hierarchy option and the columns CSV_KEY and CSV_PARENT_KEY, but you can't create connectors in a CSV import.